# Holiday cookies word attrition [computers welcome]

Tags: word, wordplay

**[This puzzle was [previously posted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80187/holiday-cookies-word-attrition-humans-only) for humans only, but it may have been a little too tough to do manually, so I'm opening it up to computers to solve the remaining unsolved words.]**

I am inspired by the story of the boy who came upon an assortment of holiday cookies beautifully arranged on a platter.  The boy quietly helped himself to a cookie and artistically rearranged the remaining cookies to make it appear as if none were missing.  Then, he helped himself to another and rearranged again.  And another.  And another.  Until all the cookies were gone.  (And that's when his mother noticed...)

It's very simple:

- I will give you a starting word.
- You will remove a letter of your choosing, and then rearrange the remaining letters to form a new word.
- Then, remove another letter and rearrange the remaining letters to form a new word.
- Then, remove another letter and rearrange the remaining letters to form a new word.
- ...
- And so on until all the letters are gone.

For example:

```
Starting word is ALTERCATIONS

-------------------------------------------

Solution:


ALTERCATIONS
                 (remove "T" and rearrange)
LACERATIONS
                 (remove "C" and rearrange)
SENATORIAL
                 (remove "A" and rearrange)
RELATIONS
                 (remove "O" and rearrange)
ENTRAILS
                 (remove "N" and rearrange)
REALIST
                 (remove "L" and rearrange)
SATIRE
                 (remove "T" and rearrange)
RAISE
                 (remove "I" and rearrange)
EARS
                 (remove "R" and rearrange)
SEA
                 (remove "E" and rearrange)
AS
                 (remove "S" and rearrange)
A
                 (remove "A" and you're done)
```

You can do as much or as little rearrangement as you like.  E.g., you are permitted to remove the "R" from BRAKE and leave BAKE, or even just snap the "-S" off the end of a word and leave all the remaining letters as they are.

As always, I construct my puzzles in such a way that they can be solved using only well-known words, so if you find yourself going down a path of increasingly obscure words, you may be overthinking it.

Multiple solution paths may exist, so don't worry if your path varies slightly from your neighbor's path, especially at the tail ends.

Below are 12 starting words.  See if you can reduce each one to nothing through attrition.

```
1.  DISSEMINATORS (solved)

2.  ENCRUSTATIONS

3.  DECENTRALIZED (solved)

4.  IMPERSONATING (solved)

5.  SHAREHOLDINGS

6.  INVESTIGATORS

7.  INDOCTRINATED (solved)

8.  REGISTRATIONS

9.  DETERIORATING (solved)

10.  INDETERMINATE

11.  REINSTALLATION

12.  RESUSCITATIONS
```

---

@hexomino — That was fast work!

Here is a solution to #8:

> REGISTRATIONS
>     REGISTRATION
>     INTEGRATORS
>     RESTARTING
>     RESTATING
>     ANGRIEST
>     SEATING
>     GIANTS
>     STING
>     TINS
>     SIN
>     IS
>     I

An alternative solution to #2:

> ENCRUSTATIONS
>     ENCRUSTATION
>     TRANSECTION
>     CONTAINERS
>     REACTIONS
>     ANCESTOR
>     COASTER
>     TRACES
>     RATES
>     RATE
>     EAT
>     AT
>     A

An alternative solution to #5:

> SHAREHOLDINGS
>     SHAREHOLDING
>     HIGHLANDERS
>     HIGHLANDER
>     HERALDING
>     ADHERING
>     READING
>     GARDEN
>     RANGE
>     NEAR
>     RAN
>     AN
>     A

An alternative solution to #6:

> INVESTIGATORS
>     INVESTIGATOR
>     INVIGORATES
>     ORIGINATES
>     ORIGINATE
>     RIGATONI
>     RIOTING
>     ORIGIN
>     GROIN
>     IRON
>     ION
>     IN
>     I

An alternative solution to #10:

> INDETERMINATE
>     INTERMEDIATE
>     DETERMINATE
>     TERMINATED
>     DETRIMENT
>     REMITTED
>     MERITED
>     TIERED
>     TRIED
>     DIET
>     TIE
>     IT
>     I

An alternative solution to #12:

> RESUSCITATIONS
>     RESUSCITATION
>     CREATIONISTS
>     CREATIONIST
>     RECITATION
>     INTRICATE
>     INTERACT
>     CERTAIN
>     RETAIN
>     INERT
>     TIRE
>     TIE
>     IT
>     I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly easier with computers

2.

> ENCRUSTATIONS 
>  ENCRUSTATION 
>  TRUNCATIONS 
>  CONSTRAINT 
>  CONSTRAIN 
>  CONTAINS 
>  CONTAIN 
>  CATION 
>  TONIC 
>  COIN 
>  ION 
>  IN 
>  I

5.

> SHAREHOLDINGS 
>  SHAREHOLDING 
>  HIGHLANDERS 
>  HIGHLANDER 
>  HERALDING 
>  HARDLINE 
>  HANDLER 
>  HANDLE 
>  ELAND 
>  LAND 
>  LAD 
>  AD 
>  A

6.

> INVESTIGATORS 
>  INVESTIGATOR 
>  INVIGORATES 
>  INVIGORATE 
>  ORIGINATE 
>  RIGATONI 
>  ORATING 
>  RATING 
>  GRAIN 
>  RING 
>  GIN 
>  IN 
>  I

10.

> INDETERMINATE 
>  INTERMEDIATE 
>  DETERMINATE 
>  TERMINATED 
>  TERMINATE 
>  MARTINET 
>  MINARET 
>  MARINE 
>  RAMIE 
>  MARE 
>  MAR 
>  AM 
>  A

11.

> REINSTALLATION 
>  ALLITERATIONS 
>  ALLITERATION 
>  RETALIATION 
>  ALTERATION 
>  RATIONALE 
>  RELATION 
>  ELATION 
>  ENTAIL 
>  INLET 
>  TINE 
>  TIN 
>  IN 
>  I

12.

> RESUSCITATIONS 
>  RESUSCITATION 
>  CREATIONISTS 
>  CREATIONIST 
>  RECITATION 
>  ITERATION 
>  INTRICATE 
>  INTERACT 
>  CATTIER 
>  ATTIRE 
>  TREAT 
>  TEAR 
>  TEA 
>  AT 
>  A

Still not sure on 8, possibly involves some more obscure words.